# Is it safe to use file_get_contents on a flock-ed file?

Tags: php, fopen

From my old-school developper POV, doing this is strange:

```
$f = fopen($this->_fileName, "r");
if ($f===false) {
    throw new Exception("bla");
}
$locked = flock($f, LOCK_SH);
if (!$locked) {
    throw new Exception("bla");
}
$content = file_get_contents($this->_fileName);
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
```

Or doing something like:

```
$f = fopen($this->_fileName, "r");
if ($f===false) {
    throw new Exception("bla");
}
$locked = flock($f, LOCK_SH);
if (!$locked) {
    throw new Exception("bla");
}
$content = fread($f, filesize($this->_fileName));
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
```

i.e. if I'm opening with `fopen()`, I *should* use `$f` all the time. But in my two samples, two functions dont use the `$f` and I'm sure they try to open the file to read some information in it: `file_get_contents()` and `filesize()`.

I could do a loop:

```
$content = ''; 
while(!feof($f)) 
    $content .= fread($f, 4096); 
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
```

But I remember that I've read some time ago that this loop is much slower than the two solutions I'm suggesting. What is the safest and the most effective way of doing this (safest comes first)?

Comment: Flock is something that you have to use everywhere in your code where you access files in order for it to make sense. If you do not - it won't work, simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All code accessing the shared resource (in this case `$this->fileName`) simply needs to agree to lock *something*, not necessarily the shared resource.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
$lock = flock('/tmp/lockfile'); 
file_put_contents('/etc/foo.ini', 'whatever');
funlock($lock);
```

Notice the thing I'm locking is not the same thing I'm overwriting.

However, traditionally `flock` is applied to the file handle for the shared file, simply because it's easier than opening another handle just for a lock file (and saves the memory allocation of said opening). There's no requirement for that, though, just programmer ease.

In general, `flock` is a means to provide a cooperative, advisory, read-write locking mechanism on top of the file system: it doesn't actually do anything to the thing being locked.

Comment: What is misleading is that the php doc talks about `fclose()` and all examples do a `flock()` then work on the same file. They don't precise it's just a mechanism totally independant from the resource **even though** it's often used this way for readability (or programmer laziness).

Comment: @olivierPons: Agree, totally. Sometimes I think the PHP docs assume people have a familiarity with the underlying C libraries.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard Note the "(pseudo-code)", there is no `funlock($lock)`, only `flock($lock, LOCK_UN)` (or possibly `fclose($lock)`)